# Cmake -version always picking up older version of the software

Tags: macos, cmake

I am trying to install Gflags which inturn requires Cmake 2.8.12 or above. I currently have Cmake 2.8.11 and i tried to install the latest version. Installation went thru without any problem, but when I run cmake -version, i still see the older version. I have tried rebooting my machine.

Hardware : MAC 10.9

Answer (score 3):

looks like a newer version of binary `cmake` placed in the `$PATH` after the old one or not in the `$PATH` at all. To check what verstion takes precedence try in bash command prompt:

```
$ which cmake
```

to see other versions:

```
$ whereis cmake
```

fix your `PATH` accordingly (in system-wide profile or your personal `~/.bashrc`) and reload `bash` by `exec bash` or close and reopen terminal window.

Anyway, you always may execute `cmake` by full (absolute) path:

```
$ cd your-project-src
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ /full/path/to/cmake ..
```

Comment: which cmake => this return /usr/bin/cmake and i see 2 cmake in the same location. whereis cmake => doesnt return anything. If i add /usr/bin/cmake to the path, its again pointing to the older version

Comment: @G3M: "_i see 2 cmake in the same location_" -- what exactly do you see? it is not possible to have 2 files with the same name in the same directory %)

Comment: Be carrefull, `which cmake` can be wrong if the command comes from an alias in your `~/.bashrc` file.